# How to export custom modules as global across the project and import by just providing the name rather than path in js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have this how do you make your custom module global accross you project and import it by providing the name of the module rather than the path like the modules in npm ecosystem

```
import CustomModule from "custom-modules";
```

Comment: Are you using a tool like webpack?

Comment: no i am currently using express i don't think it uses webpack but react does. Do i need a bundler to do this?

Comment: Webpack has the ability to use aliases. I'm currently looking at node

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for a while i found the answer. You have to add your exports in package.json in order to use them with the name or path provided in package.json. e.g.

```
 {
  "name": "my-mod",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./lib/index.js",
    "./lib": "./lib/index.js",
    "./lib/index": "./lib/index.js",
    "./lib/index.js": "./lib/index.js",
    "./feature": "./feature/index.js",
    "./feature/index.js": "./feature/index.js",
    "./package.json": "./package.json"
  }
}
```

You can go [Here](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#modules-packages) for more details